# Adding JavaScript panel into GWT panel

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I want to add an external JavaScript file that contains a colored panel and one button into a GWT panel. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Stackoveflow 101 - Do not update a question by posting an Answer!!! Either edit your question with new information or comment on the answer provided seeking clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your panel with a button in GWT, set an ID on this panel that your native JavaScript code needs, and then execute a [native JavaScript method using JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI?hl=de).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to invoke a function in an imported javascript file ( library ).

Step 1 - 
You would need to load the js file via your module gwt xml file with tag `<script src="thirparty.js" />`

Step 2 - 
Use JSNI to get element (panel) from imported thirdparty lib. Create a div or use innerhtml and set it to the GWT panel.

If you are trying to find a third party color picker -

```
http://www.auroris.net/gwt/colorpicker/
http://code.google.com/p/auroris/
```

Answer (score 0):

No i can't create button with gwt

I only can create a empty panel in gwt and i add over a javascript panel.